# while Statement breaking loop

Tags: c++

I added a while statement around my code so that the user could repeat the process as my teacher instructed, the way I did it worked on other code but for some reason it broke this one I could use help making it work please and thank you. The point of the code is to just flip 10000 coins and output the number of heads and tails. Thanks for any and all help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Keaton Graffis 12/22/2012

int coin()
{
    int flip;
    // assign random numbers
    flip = rand() % 2 + 1;

    return (flip);
}

int main()
{
    char choice = 'y';
    while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    {
        double numFlips = 10000;
        int count, face, heads = 0, tails = 0;

        // initialize the random number generator
        srand(static_cast<int>(time(0)));

        // generate and count the number of heads and tails
        for (int count = 1; count <= numFlips; count++)
        {
            face = coin();
            if (face == 1)
                heads++;
            else
                tails++;

        }

        cout << "The number flips: " << numFlips << endl;
        cout << "The number of heads: " << heads << endl;
        cout << "The number of tails: " << tails << endl;

        // Asks user if they would like to go again(makes cod enot run, not sure why, this works on all my other code)
        while (1)
        {
            cout << "Would you like to play again [Y]es or [N]o?\n";
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y' || choice == 'n' || choice == 'N')
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it broke? What is it doing? Does it give you any error messages? If so, post it here. With just your code and a claim that says something is broke will not help us help you.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity will be more clear next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after the `while` condition of the first loop. Only full statements are terminated by a `;`.

---

Notes:

- Since C++11, better facilities for random number generation are provided in the `<random>` header. Use these!

Comment: Thank you for the help, did not see that ; . It works great now.

Comment: @frodo12311 Then, as soon as your able to, accept an answer to mark this problem as solved and to give me some rep.

Comment: Really new to using any kind of forum, how do I do that?

Comment: @frodo12311 There is a tick under the vote count of the answers. Click on the one of the answer you want to accept and it should turn green.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you again.